# "File not found." for clean URLS

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I've installed the nginx + php-fpm + mysql stack in my Mac using homebrew.

MacOsX: 10.9.2
Nginx Version: 1.6.1
Document Root: /Users/raj/Sites/
Project Dir: /Users/raj/Sites/projects/newproject
Url: 127.0.0.1/projects/newproject

My /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf configuration looks like:

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include         mime.types;
    #include            /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    # gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root  /Users/raj/Sites;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            index  index.php;
            autoindex on;
        }

        # configure *.PHP requests
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

If I open the url: `127.0.0.1/projects/newproject` or `127.0.0.1/projects/newproject/index.php` it works fine.

But if i open any other url `http://127.0.0.1/projects/newproject/users/login` or even `127.0.0.1/projects/newproject/index.php/users/login` then it gives me the following error:

```
File not found.
```

And the error.log says:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream
```

**[EDIT]**

If I add the following lines in 'location ~ .php$ {' block:

```
try_files       $uri /index.php;
```

gives the error:

```
rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php"
```

**[EDIT2]**
Additionally I found the following error log when trying to restart the FPM:

```
[pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
```

Comment: [This answer](http://serverfault.com/a/576026/218590) suggest that php-pfm can't read your file. Did you check the permissions?

Comment: I have given 755 permission though, still no any luck. `chown -R www-data:www-data ~/Sites` gives chown: www-data: illegal group name

Comment: The error message `'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root` was indicated that you aren't not start php-fpm daemon as root. Maybe this is source of your permission problem.

Comment: @masegaloeh can you give me more insights on this please. very new to nginx + php-fpm stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It was so simple fix.
Change line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

to

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /projects/newproject/index.php;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your configuration has two obvious problems:

1. Your `location @handler` is completely unnecessary and redundant. This is already covered by your existing `index` and `try_files` directive. Remove that `location` entirely and fix `try_files`.

   ```
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   ```
2. You have placed your `root` directives in the wrong places.

   `root` should be defined in the `server` block, not in each `location` block. This is one of the [most common nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

   Remove all of the `root` directives from each `location` block, and place the correct `root` directive within the `server` block, not within any `location`.

Once you've gotten your configuration to this baseline, you should find things start working again, or you might have a different issue which is easier to deal with.

Comment: I edited as per you suggestion (see above), but still the same error(File not found.)